# Adding two arrays by reference

Tags: javascript, arrays, reference

I have two arrays that I instantiate as objects.  I would like to concantenate these two arrays and I would like to do it by reference.  Is there a way to do this?  I know objects are by reference, but that's as far as I got.

```
// array 1
function gdb() {
    this.data = [{
        "id":"AA",
        "pos": "0"
    },
    {
        "id":"AB",
        "pos":"3"
    }
    ]
    ;
}

// array 2
function xdb() {
    this.data = [{
        "id":"CM",
        "pos": "4"
    },
    {
        "id":"CR",
        "pos":"7"
    }
    ]
    ;
}

// arrays combined
function gdb() {
    this.data = [{
        "id":"AA",
        "pos": "0"
    },
    {
        "id":"AB",
        "pos":"3"
    },
    {
        "id":"CM",
        "pos": "4"
    },
    {
        "id":"CR",
        "pos":"7"
    }
    ]
    ;
}
```

Comment: Your best bet is to use [`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) (this returns a new array). You could also use repeated calls to `Array.push()`

Comment: @NullUserException I'm not sure that's by reference - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Comment: Every time you instantiate a `gdb` or `xdb` object, you will be instantiating a new array.

Comment: @bfavaretto The arrays are passed by reference (in the sense that they aren't passed by value), but the resulting array is a shallow copy.

Comment: Am I the only one confused about why there are two gdb functions?

Comment: So if I use **var v = new xdb();** and pass v to a function, I understand that that's by reference.  I was hoping i could add the two arrays by reference to save memory.

Answer (score 1):

To concatenate arrays just use their [`concat` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat). I'm not sure what you mean with "by reference", though. The new array (which contains all the values) properties will point to the same objects as the two separate arrays' properties before. Yet, the new array will not change if you assign new objects to the old array properties, that's quite impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are objects and they're passed by reference by default. I am not sure if you're trying to use those functions as Constructors (it looks like it). Is this what you need?

```
function ConstructorOne() {
    this.data1 = [
        {"id":"AA", "pos":"0"},
        {"id":"AB", "pos":"3"}
    ];
}

function ConstructorTwo() {
    // Inheritance 
    ConstructorOne.call(this);

    this.data2 = [
        {"id":"CM", "pos":"4"},
        {"id":"CR", "pos":"7"}
    ];
}

var obj = new ConstructorTwo();
obj.data = obj.data1.concat(obj.data2);

// Delete old ones if not needed - don't otherwise
//delete obj.data1;
//delete obj.data2;

// Making changes to the data property, will also 
// change data1 & data2 from the constructors, proving 
// that data is just a reference of data1 + data2
obj.data[2]['id'] = "PIZZA";
obj.data[1]['id'] = "APPLE";
obj.data[0]['id'] = "LETTUCE";

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: No, you are not changing the `data` property, but the objects in the array.

Comment: The data property's value is an array of objects. If I'm modifying the objects, it means that the data property, which is an array, now holds different data - or objects of different data. Hence the data property has now been modified. Makes sense?

Comment: Yeah, but I think "holding the modified objects" is a better wording, since technically you do not modify the array, but the objects referenced by it.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're trying to clarify. Totally valid point. Yes, the modification is happening because of the object references and not because of any array references going on. That's because concat() just returns a new array and not a magic reference to both of the arrays. It is very easy to forget that while looking at the code. I admit I confused myself with my own code there! Thanks for clarifying though... very helpful!